# How to make erlang see that an atom is a PID

Tags: concurrency, erlang

I have the following code:

```
-module(circle).
-export([proc/1,mother/0,chain/1]).


-spec mother() -> none().
mother() ->
    register(mother,self()).

-spec proc(pid()) -> none().
proc(Next) when is_pid(Next) -> 
    receive 
        {_, Msg} -> Next ! {self(), Msg}
    end.

-spec chain(integer()) -> pid().
chain(0) -> mother;
chain(N) when is_integer(N) ->
    spawn(circle,proc,chain(N-1)).
```

It compiles as expected however whenever I run, it throws a bad argument error when the chain reaches the `0` argument. This is because erlang treats the mother as an atom however I have previously called the `mother` function which should've registered `mother` as a `pid`.

I initially thought the mother does not get registered however after having called this in the console:

```
-> circle:mother().
-> mother ! {abc}.
abc
```

I was able to deduce from here that mother does get treated like a Pid. How can I make the code work? How can I make erlang see that mother is a PID?

What I'm trying to achieve is to build N processes in a circle.

Comment: If my answer to solve your issue do you think you could post the stacktrace from the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Registered process name doesn't turn into pid. 
Here is type specification of destination in [erlang:send/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#send-2) which is the same as `!` operator:

```
dst() = pid()
      | port()
      | (RegName :: atom())
      | {RegName :: atom(), Node :: node()}
```

As you see send takes many types as destination.
You don't need to care about that, so just remove that guard; make another clause for atom case or append to guard `orelse is_atom(Next)`.

```
-spec proc(pid() | atom()) -> none().
proc(Next) -> 
    receive 
        {_, Msg} -> Next ! {self(), Msg}
    end.
```

You have one error in `spawn(circle,proc,chain(N-1)).`

[spawn/3](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#spawn-3) takes list of arguments as third argument:

```
spawn(circle,proc,[chain(N-1)]).
```

I don't see any benefit from registering a root process. If closing a circle was problematic with pids only, here is how you can do it:

```
chain(N) -> 
    chain(N, self()).
chain(0, Mother) -> Mother;
chain(N, Mother) when is_integer(N) ->
    spawn(circle,proc,[chain(N-1, Mother)]).
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to invoke `mother/0` in the `chain(0)` clause you must correct the clause so that it reads:

```
chain(0) -> mother();
```

As it currently stands you are simply returning an atom, since all you have in the body of the function clause is an atom, and not the invocation of a function. Example:

```
something() -> fun_name. %=> returns `fun_name`
something() -> fun_name(). %=> invokes `fun_name/0` and returns the result of the call.
```

Comment: calling `mother()` will attempt to register the `self` to the atom mother. This is a recursive call (probably a very bad one) so this is 100% going to fail

Comment: When I say "bad one". I'm referring to the recursive nature of my function.